# What is the best way to print a webpage as you see it?

Tags: html, css, printing, fonts, cross-browser

I'm not sure if the question is accurate as I've phrased it, but I can't think of a better way, so bear with it.

Goal: There is a `W x H` area of a browser window you want to print on a `W x H` piece of paper.

Assumptions:

1. The page is static HTML and CSS. It does not change over time, you cannot interact with it, and it renders in exactly the same way in every browser.
2. You use `@media print` and `display: none` to ensure all classes outside the `W x H` don't show up in print.

Things to consider:

1. What's the best cross-platform way to specify the `W x H` (lets say its a `div`)? Given the same printer driver settings regarding paper-size, DPI, margins, etc. is there a way to make it show up the same size on print? Does the screen's PPI matter?
2. Fonts. The printer may not have the required fonts. *The OS* may not have the required fonts, if its a web-font. Is there a 'best' way to print that gets these through? Is there a specific way to use web-fonts that allows this? Or is there a way to rasterize the page at the printer's DPI and print as an image would?

Comment: Take a screenshot and print it :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "same size"? Do you actually mean the same size physical on the screen in inches/cm, or do you mean pixels? Maybe you could explain the larger picture. What you are trying to achieve? In any case printer fonts are completely irrelevant. Nowadays anything that is printed, is printed as a graphic, even "pure text". Virtually no modern program actually prints text using the fonts on the printer.

Comment: @RoToRa, I mean sized so that it doesn't need to be scaled to fit the page when its being printed. What I'm trying to do is use HTML/CSS to design a set of 'pages' to print. Even though I restricted myself to just Chrome on Windows 7, the number of strange quirks that crop up when it goes to the browser's Print Preview is irritating. Since I'm sticking to a single configuration, I temporarily dealt with sizing through trial and error, but fonts are still a problem. With both issues, a 'clean' solution seems like its always just out of reach.

Comment: Could you post a example web page? Maybe that would hel.

Answer (score 0):

The dirty way of doing it is to screenshot the webpage, then print the screenshot with something else. That way you're ensuring it comes out as you see it.

For [example](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki)

Unfortunately each browser printer preview will manipulate and understand div's in different ways, and most of them will just automatically wrap the content. The only way to get around that is to specify fixed widths e.g. 1000px for the div, and style it with { overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; }

With fonts, yes there is a way to install fonts on the user's computer. The other easy solution is just to make them pictures i.e. PNG's. For installing, checkout Google Web Fonts (and Google search will give you similar results).